# How to return set of new rows in postgres function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I am using Postgres 14.4 and have table records with jsonb `form` column `name`, `sex`, and `city`.

```
id | form
a | { "name": "John", "sex": "Male", "city": "Amsterdam" }
b | { "name": "Eva", "sex": "Female", "city": "London" }
c | { "name": "Doe", "sex": "Male", "city": "Amsterdam" }
```

I wanted to return the data embedded by function.

Here is what I tried

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_report_trial()
RETURNS records AS $$
    SELECT form #>> '{sex}', '{city}', count(*) as count 
      FROM records GROUP BY form #>> '{sex}', form #>> '{city}';
$$ LANGUAGE SQL STABLE;
```

Returning `void` doesn't work since I am returning new aggregate data as specified
here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html

The error says `return type mismatch in function declared to return records`.
How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Btw: `records` is a horrible name for a table. It's like naming your son or daughter "Child"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION generate_report_trial()
  RETURNS table (sex text, city text, num_rows bigint)
AS 
$$
  SELECT form #>> '{sex}', 
         form #>> '{city}', 
         count(*) as count 
  FROM records 
  GROUP BY form #>> '{sex}', form #>> '{city}';
$$ 
LANGUAGE SQL 
STABLE;
```

You need to use it the from clause then:

```
select *
from generate_report_trial();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return the table via any variable. PostgreSQL has no table variables.
When you create a table, PostgreSQL creates a composite type with the same name. Not table type - compound type - record.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION generate_report_trial()
RETURNS records AS $$
    SELECT form #>> '{sex}', '{city}', count(*) as count 
      FROM records GROUP BY form #>> '{sex}', form #>> '{city}';
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: The important part is the `returns` clause which you didn't change. The structure of the result doesn't match the type definition of `records`. And it's an invalid PL/pgSQL structure as well.